# Why do the input and output file sizes differ in this case? Differences of several bytes

Tags: c#, .net-core

Why does this method create a non-input file? The differences are very small, but there are, I don't know why. The problem probably only affects signed files, because it repeats every time, and I've never noticed it in an unsigned file. These are the differences of several bytes.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileAddress = Console.ReadLine();
    var newAddress = Console.ReadLine();
    var file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileAddress);
    var bigInt = new BigInteger(file);
    var byteArrayFromBigInt = bigInt.ToByteArray();
    File.WriteAllBytes(newAddress, byteArrayFromBigInt);
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTgAt.png)
The method using Base64 works fine but is slower.
I use dot net core 3.1

Comment: What are you trying to do by creating a `BigInteger` from the entire contents of the file?

Comment: This is sample code to see if there are differences between this approach and using base64 encoding. It turned out that they are, but I don't know where they come from.

Comment: Base64 encoding and creating a BigInteger aren't even close to being the same thing... why are you trying to compare the two?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Numerics_BigInteger__ctor_System_Byte___) for `BigInteger`, it seems that the `ToByteArray()` method adds two zero bytes to the start to represent a positive number:

> this method returns a byte array with the highest-order bit of the
>   highest-order byte in the array set to zero for positive values, there
>   is no chance of misinterpreting a positive value as negative.

My guess is that an arbitrary signed executable file doesn't generally begin with two zero bytes, so them being added accounts for the difference in file sizes you're seeing.